# MySQL - Outputting correct order for items that have a hierarchy?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL table and I need to output the results in the correct order.

```
id     title     parent_id     display_order     level
20     company   NULL          0                 0
25     contact   NULL          1                 0
26     sales     NULL          2                 0
21     about     20            0                 1
22     team      20            1                 1
23     services  20            2                 1
24     apps      23            0                 2
```

The correct order would be the following:

```
Company
    about
    team
    services
        apps
Contact
Sales
```

I can't figure out how to make a query that will order by "level" and then "display_order" but ensuring that child items following their parent.

I'm looking for a MySQL answer but if you have a suggesting on how to parse the results with PHP, I'd consider that as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you try `recursive` php-function?

Comment: Your schema kinda sucks for accomplishing what you want.  Is altering the schema an option, or is the requirement to hack around it?

Answer (score 0):

I often used php-function for get array categories with level

```
public function getCategoryTreeForParentId($parent_id = 0) {
  $categories = array();
  $this->db->from('categories');
  $this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
  $result = $this->db->get()->result();
  foreach ($result as $mainCategory) {
    $category = array();
    $category['id'] = $mainCategory->id;
    $category['name'] = $mainCategory->name;
    $category['parent_id'] = $mainCategory->parent_id;
    $category['sub_categories'] = $this->getCategoryTreeForParentId($category['id']);
    $categories[$mainCategory->id] = $category;
  }
  return $categories;
}
```

When you echo in html, you can depend on `level` value for classify your categories

Comment: I'm really looking for something that can just reorder my results and not created a nested hierarchy